# How can we switch to certain Application programatically or through cmd

Tags: vb6

I have vb app running on Windows Surface(tablet) 
I need to switch to that application when application is minimized or not in focus when user clicks to apps icon

Already tried AppFocus but not working
and some shell comands too

I just need to replicate the behaviour of task manager's switch to MyApp when clicking the tile of my app on windows 8 tiles or icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this..

```
Shell FileName
```

Where FileName is the full path and file name plus extension.

```
Shell "F:\ExeFiles\SomeProgram.exe"
```

If you don't want multiple instances running then check in your called app using...

```
Sub ActivatePrevInstance()

    'if there is a previous instance of this app activate it and terminate
    Dim OldTitle As String, PrevHndl As Long, Result As Long
    'Save the title of the application.
    OldTitle = App.Title
    'Rename the title of this application
    App.Title = "unwanted instance"
    'Attempt to get window handle using VB6 class name
    If PrevHndl = 0 Then PrevHndl = FindWindow("ThunderRT6Main", OldTitle)
    If PrevHndl = 0 Then
        'No previous instance found. Restore name
        App.Title = OldTitle
    Else
        PrevHndl = GetWindow(PrevHndl, GW_HWNDPREV)
        Result = OpenIcon(PrevHndl)                     'Restore the program.
        Result = SetForegroundWindow(PrevHndl)          'Activate
        End                                             'close application
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes i tried that approach but there is problem with that, when my app is open and not in focus and i am working with another app like excel etc then if i go to start screen in windows 8 and clicks the my app tile icon resulting it gets me back to the   app i was working on before comming to the start sxreen lets say excel in this case or candycrush

Comment: If you want to switch focus from app A to app B, which is already running, this link may help.

<https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/44db8d76-eb03-4182-8493-5aef3bec01b3/how-to-switch-to-another-application-from-mine?forum=vblanguage>